# What does "as a matter of" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrases

If it is agreed that the action in question is within the scope of the functions of
the Organization but it is alleged that it has been initiated or carried out in a manner
not in conformity with the division of functions among the several organs which the
Charter prescribes, one moves to the internal plane, to the internal structure of the
Organization. If the action was taken by the wrong organ, it was irregular **as a matter
of** that internal structure, but this would not necessarily mean that the expense
incurred was not an expense of the Organization. Both national and international
law contemplate cases in which the body corporate or politic may be bound, as to
third parties, by an *ultra vires* [acting or done beyond one's legal power or authority] act of an agent.

Answer (score 1):

From context the phrase means the same as "in terms of", and I think that would be a better expression.

The action in question was irregular because it was carried out by the wrong internal sub-organization of a larger organization, but the larger organization is still responsible for the expense.